# Excel: CountIf (cell1 > cell2 AND cell3 > cell4)

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need to compare two sets of two columns and find the count of number of IDs that match a certain criteria.

```
A            B             C           D             E
ID:        ListNum:      RefNum:     List2Num:      Ref2Num:          
1           10             5           12            6
2            3             7           10            2
3           12             8            1            5
4            2            15           13            4
5            4            11            2            8
6            6             9            1            3
```

Let's say that the cell containing ID = "1" is A2 and it goes down to A7

I have to count the number of IDs that have a ListNum that is higher than the RefNum AND also have a List2Num that is higher than Ref2Num. Both criteria must be satisfied in order to count the ID.

I used the following formula: =COUNT(IF(B2:B7 > C2:C7) & (D2:D7 > E2:E7))

I get a value, but it's not the right count (it's taking the total for both conditions rather than only counting it once). The final answer should be 1. Any help would be appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One reason why yours didn't work:  In your formula you use & to mean AND, but & actually concatenate strings.

## Option 1: Array Formula

IF and AND don't work on arrays so a normal formula containing them won't work.  So use an array formula instead:

You need to enter this as an array formula (you need to press control-shift-enter instead of enter when you put the formula in):

```
=SUM((B2:B7 > C2:C7)*(D2:D7 > E2:E7))
```

When it is in the cell it will display in braces to show it is an array formula.  Like so:

```
{=SUM((B2:B7 > C2:C7)*(D2:D7 > E2:E7))}
```

In this formula the X>Y will return 1 or 0 for true or false.  So multiplication is the same as AND and addition is the same as OR.  Then `(B2:B7 > C2:C7)*(D2:D7 > E2:E7)` means `B2:B7 > C2:C7 AND D2:D7 > E2:E7` and it returns an array of 1 and 0 which are then summed up to get the count.

## Option 2: SUMPRODUCT

There is a normal function whose sole purpose is to multiply arrays together and then add them up the same way as the array formula does:  SUMPRODUCT

The problem with SUMPRODUCT is that the arrays must be numbers and not logical true and false values so any of these works:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(B2:B7 > C2:C7),--(D2:D7 > E2:E7))
=SUMPRODUCT((B2:B7 > C2:C7)*1,(D2:D7 > E2:E7)*1)
=SUMPRODUCT((B2:B7 > C2:C7)+0,(D2:D7 > E2:E7)+0)
```

And this does not:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((B2:B7 > C2:C7),(D2:D7 > E2:E7))
```

But SUMPRODUCT is a normal function so you don't need to enter it with control-shift-enter.

Comment: Thank you for the thorough explanation! I tried the solution by @lenwe and it gave an answer, but it was a different number compared to the answer obtained from your formulas. I'm not sure why (does Excel 2010 support lenwe's formula or does it need a higher version?).

Comment: @FrootLoops Hmmm.   I didn't actually try it.  I assumed he wouldn't offer something that didn't work.  I will try to make it work and edit my answer accordingly.

Comment: @FrootLoops  You are correct.  The COUNTIFS version doesn't work.  And I can't make it work.

Comment: I tried using COUNTIFS on another Excel version and it also gave an alternate number, so I'll stick to your SUMPRODUCT version. Thank you again for cross checking!

Answer (score 0):

Try entering this formula into cell `F1`:

```
=IF(AND(B1 > C1, D1 > E1), 1, 0)
```

Then just take the sum of the `F` column for however many rows you really have, and you should be left with the answer (which is `1` for the sample data you gave above).

Comment: I tried =IF(AND(B2:B7 > C2:C7, D2:D7 > E2:E7), 1, 0) and ended up with 0.
Do you mind explaining your answer a little bit more? Thank you

Comment: @FrootLoops  He wanted you to make a helper column in F that contained 1 for true or 0 for false and then you could just put =COUNT(F2:F7) somewhere.  But if you want to use ranges you could use an array formula - maybe I should add an answer for that...

Comment: @JerryJeremiah Thanks for the comment.  Your explanation is the way to go IMO...couldn't bring it to mind at the time.

Answer (score 0):

If you put a simple AND formula next to your table, you can autofill that all the way down. Next, you could count the number of True values in that column (see pic). You could combine into an IF statement as Tim suggests.

The two formulas would be

- "=AND(B2>C2,D2>E2)"
- "=COUNTIF(G2:G7,TRUE)"

[Link to picture of possible solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jB1Ts.jpg)